# sap.m.IconTabBar: How to Make Header Sticky / Only Content Scrollable

Tags: sapui5

I'm looking for a way to make a [sap.m.IconTabBar](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.IconTabBar) sticky, meaning that the tab bar stays fixed while you can scroll the contents. As far as I can see, there is no standard attribute support for this. Anyone implemented this?

PS: Should be possible by using CSS attribute `position: fixed` to the header part of the component.

Answer (score 1):

here my comment again as answer:

In the example i wrapped the content of the `sap.m.IconTabBar` in a `sap.m.ScrollContainer` and set the `vertical` property to true.

http://jsbin.com/luqurosaye/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Would be awesome if there was a way to set the height of the ScrollContainer to 100%.

Comment: @Marc In case you still wonder: You just need to enable `stretchContentHeight` additionally in IconTabBar as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47750244/5846045)

Answer (score 0):

### With a [scroll enabled container](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/66029f6f5a554a4eb700676bec1460dc) within `sap.m.IconTabFilter`

1. Make sure that the parent of `sap.m.IconTabBar` has also a fixed `height` value (e.g. `"100%"`).
2. Enable [**`stretchContentHeight`**](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.IconTabBar/methods/setStretchContentHeight) in `sap.m.IconTabBar` so that it covers the whole available area.
3. Use a scroll enabled container for the actual content that needs to have the scrolling.

```xml
<IconTabBar xmlns="sap.m" stretchContentHeight="true" applyContentPadding="false">
  <items>
    <IconTabFilter>
      <!-- Optionally: a nested View with 100% height -->
      <!-- Mandatory: a scroll enabled container with height 100% such as sap.m.Page, sap.m.ScrollContainer, sap.f.DynamicPage, ... -->
      <ScrollContainer horizontal="false" vertical="true" height="100%" width="100%">
        <!-- Your content to scroll -->
      </ScrollContainer>
    </IconTabFilter>
  </items>
  <!-- <content> -->
    <!-- Or here for all icon tabs -->
  <!-- </content> -->
</IconTabBar>
```

**Sample from the Demo Kit:** https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.IconTabBar/sample/sap.m.sample.IconTabBarStretchContent

---

### With a scroll enabled container outside of [`sap.m.IconTabHeader`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.IconTabHeader)

In case you have a `sap.m.IconTabHeader` instead of `IconTabBar`:

```xml
<Page xmlns="sap.m" enableScrolling="false">
  <IconTabHeader>
    <!-- ...  -->
  </IconTabHeader>
  <ScrollContainer horizontal="false" vertical="true" height="100%" width="100%">
    <!-- Your content to scroll -->
  </ScrollContainer>
</Page>
```

In contrast to the approach with `sap.m.IconTabBar`:

- `sap.m.IconTabHeader` needs its parent container to have its own scrolling disabled.

  - For Page, `enableScrollable="false"`.
  - For Dialog, `verticalScrolling="false"`.
- The content is unassociated with the `IconTabHeader`.
- Some features from `IconTabBar` (such as `expandable`) are missing.