# IconTabBar and ScrollContainer Issue

Tags: sapui5

Does anybody know a solution to use a Panel oder [sap.m.Table](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.Table) inside the [ScrollContainer](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.ScrollContainer)? No matter what parameter I change, the result is still the same. The target should be a Table or Panel including a scrollbar but a scrollbar appears for nearly the whole site; in this case for the whole **IconTabBar**.

## My XML-View

```
<IconTabBar expanded="true" expandable="false" select="showSource" width="auto">
  <items>
    <IconTabFilter text="Privileges">
      <ScrollContainer height="100%" width="100%" horizontal="false" vertical="true">
        <Table id="privilegesTable" items="{/callbackData1}" fixedLayout="true">
          <columns>
            <Column>
              <Label text="User"/>
            </Column>
            <Column minScreenWidth="Desktop" demandPopin="true" hAlign="Center">
              <Label text="Object Type"/>
            </Column>
            <Column minScreenWidth="Desktop" demandPopin="true" hAlign="Center">
              <Label text="Grantor"/>
            </Column>
            <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" hAlign="Right"/>
          </columns>
          <items>
            <ColumnListItem>
              <cells>
                <ObjectIdentifier title="{grantee}"/>
              </cells>
              <Text text="{object_type}"/>
              <Text text="{grantor}"/>
              <MenuButton text="Fix it" id="fixButton">
                <menu>
                  <Menu itemSelected="onMenuAction">
                    <items>
                      <MenuItem icon="sap-icon://call"/>
                      <MenuItem icon="sap-icon://lateness"/>
                      <MenuItem icon="sap-icon://key-user-settings"/>
                    </items>
                  </Menu>
                </menu>
              </MenuButton>
            </ColumnListItem>
          </items>
        </Table>
      </ScrollContainer>
    </IconTabFilter>
    <IconTabFilter>
    ...
    </IconTabFilter>
  </items>
</IconTabBar>
```

## How It Looks Like

[image: UI5 padding between IconTabBar and content]

As you can see in the picture above, there is a gap between the Table and the Scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the sap.m.Page propertry enableScrolling to false. this deactivates the scrolling for the whole page. now the scroll container should get active. but careful, either the scroll container need a determined height or it's parent container.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues described in the question.

1. How to remove the padding between the table and IconTabBar
   **Solution:** Disable [`applyContentPadding`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.IconTabBar/methods/setApplyContentPadding) in IconTabBar.
2. How to make only the content scrollable
   **Solution:** Enable `stretchContentHeight` in IconTabBar or use IconTabHeader as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47750244/5846045