# m.IconTabBar: How do I make tab's content scrollable?

Tags: sapui5

I have a view structure like this:

```xml
<mvc:View>
  <IconTabBar>
    <items>
      <IconTabFilter>
        <SplitApp/>
      </IconTabFilter>
      <IconTabFilter>
        <Panel>
        </Panel>
        <Panel>
        </Panel>
      </IconTabFilter>
    </items>
  </IconTabBar>
</mvc:View>
```

SplitApp looks fine and allows scrolling its content, but panels overflow and no scrolling is enabled. I thought I should wrap either `IconTabBar` or panels into some control like `Page`, `VerticalLayout`, or `VBox`, but nothing changes. Also I tried to set `overflow:scroll` for `IconTabBar` in CSS but in this case, the content of last panel moves out of `IconTabBar`.

What can I do?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47750244/5846045

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sap.m.IconTabBar: How to Make Header Sticky / Only Content Scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555097/sap-m-icontabbar-how-to-make-header-sticky-only-content-scrollable)

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works:

```html
<mvc:View>
  <IconTabBar stretchContentHeight="true">
    <items>
      <IconTabFilter>
        <SplitApp/>
      </IconTabFilter>
      <IconTabFilter>
        <ScrollContainer height="100%" vertical="true">
          <Panel>
          </Panel>
          <Panel>
          </Panel>
        </ScrollContainer>
      </IconTabFilter>
    </items>
  </IconTabBar>
</mvc:View>
```