# Scrolling Issue when Page placed within Page in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I have a requirement where I need to place an `sap.m.Page` within another `sap.m.Page`, which I am aware is not recommended. The issue I'm facing is that I'm trying to enable scrolling for only the outer page; but the scrolling does not dynamically increase as I expand content inside the inner page. There is a lot of vertical content inside the inner page and is not entirely visible since the scrolling does not increase along with the expanded panels.

Even [this](https://answers.sap.com/questions/11346205/not-able-to-display-a-sapmpage-inside-the-content-.html) does not resolve my issue. Kindly assist.

SAPUI5 version: 1.38.37

Layout of the outer page:

```xml
<mvc:View ...>
    <Page showHeader="false">
        <content>
            <IconTabBar>
                <items>
                    <IconTabFilter>
                        <content>
                            <mvc:XMLView viewName="namespace.view.InnerView1" displayBlock="true"/>
                        </content>
                    </IconTabFilter>
                    <IconTabSeparator icon=""/>
                    .
                    //multiple IconTabFilters here
                    .
                </items>
            </IconTabBar>
        </content>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Layout of the inner page (InnerView1):

```xml
<mvc:View ...>
    <Page showHeader="false" enableScrolling="false">
        <content>
            .
            //multiple expandable/collapsible Panels here
            .
        </content>
        <footer floatingFooter="false">
            <Toolbar>
                <ToolbarSpacer/>
                .
                //multiple Buttons here
                .
            </Toolbar>
        </footer>
    </Page>  
</mvc:View>
```

The Panels in the inner page are initially collapsed but they are expandable. But if all Panels are expanded in the running app, then the last couple of Panels are not accessible with the scrolling. i.e. the scrollbar does not adjust as per the panels' height.

Comment: Hi! I don't get why do you need an Page in your inner view. Is it because of the toolbar?

Comment: Does the outer page contain only the `<IconTabBar>`? If so, why does it have to stay scrollable? Are you trying to achieve something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47750244/5846045?

Answer (score -2):

Try using:

```
enableScrolling="false" //for disabling
enableScrolling="true" //for enabling
```